# How to set up HTTPS on root domain and www domain on Akamai?

Tags: https, dns, cdn, akamai

I'm setting up `www.example.com` on Akamai with HTTPS. I point `www.example.com` to the Akamai Edge hostname and add the `www.example.com` domain to my already existing SAN cert on Akamai.

My DNS provider does not allow me to set up `CNAME` records on root domains so I ca not point `example.com` to the Akamai Edge hostname

I use the workaround of pointing `example.com` to the origin server and implementing a redirect to `www.example.com` there. But how do I secure `https://example.com` so the user does not get an SSL error before being redirected to `www.example.com`? If I secure it using a certificate for `example.com`, can I just configure example.com as the origin hostname on Akamai? Will that not cause issue when Akamai tries to download content from the origin server to the edge servers because all pages on the origin server redirect to `www.example.com`, i.e. back to the edge server?

Comment: *My DNS provider does not allow me to set up CNAME records on root domains*. not just your DNS providers but everyone. Per the protocol `CNAME` records can not cohabit with other ones, and at apex you already have a least `NS` and `SOA` records, so no `CNAME` allowed here. This is only circumvented/simulated by some providers offering non standard ALIAS records or equivalent.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yeah so my understanding was that, as you mentioned, some DNS providers (I believe AWS Route 53) allow an ALIAS record as a workaround for a CNAME. Given that's not the crux of my issue, I just summarized it as my DNS provider not allowing me to create CNAME's on root domain records.

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [sf] or [webmasters.se] (although I encourage you to check their respecting help centers to make sure this question is on topic), since you're not asking about programming per se.

Answer (score 4):

Akamaizing the root of a domain is typically not possible because of the inability to CNAME. We recommend using Akamai's Edge DNS to help overcome this. You will have a built-in option to set-up an 'AKAMAITLC' record which can translate the root of a domain and map it to the best Akamai EdgeServer.

Alternatively, you can set-up a redirect service that redirects example.com to www.example.com, but that will not reach Akamai until the request for www.example.com is made.

The AKAMAITLC record typically helps with increasing performance for DNS lookup but I have to specify that Akamai Edge DNS is a separate product and your organization might not have it included.

I hope it helps, happy to help out. /Mike

Answer (score 0):

The problem of doing the redirect from your origin is that your IP's will be revealed and is something, because of security reasons, you may want to avoid.

In many cases, a dedicated host is used only for this or if you want to go serverless you could use a provider that allows [CNAME flattening](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/) and from there do the redirect if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To use Akamai with your apex (root) domain **you must use Akamai DNS for your domain**. If you're using Akamai DNS it's just a click on a button to add the root domain to a property.